# docker-compose.yml invalid type

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.0'
services:
  asdf-db:
    container_name: asdf-db
    build: ./asdf/db
    ports:
      - 5435:5432 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: exit 0

  asdf-service:
    container_name: asdf-service
    build: ./
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/asdf'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000 # expose ports - HOST:CONTAINER
    environment:
      - APP_SETTINGS=asdf.config.DevelopmentConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@asdf-db:5432/asdf_dev
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@asdf-db:5432/asdf_test
    depends_on:
      asdf-db:
        condition: service_healthy
      links:
        - asdf-db
```

when i run `docker-compose up -d` i get the following error message:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.asdf-db: 'healthcheck'
services.asdf-service.depends_on contains an invalid type, it should be an array
```

I've tried switching the version to 2.1 and then i get the following error message:

```
ERROR: The Compose file '.\docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.asdf-service.depends_on.links contains ["asdf-db"], which is an invalid type, it should be an object
```

How do I change asdf-db to an object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Healthcheck was added in `2.1` so you need at least that version.

In 2.1 version, you have `links` within `depends_on`, whereas it should be in the same level.